# How to create an array to scale from 0 until user input

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program that prints out an array based on user input. The array needs to start from 0 and scale to the number enter by user. So if user inputs 5 the the array values will be [0][1][2][3][4][5]. For some reason my code just prints out 0.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
cout << "Enter the value of n: ";
int n;
cin >> n;
int *arr1 = new int[n];

for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
    arr1[i] = 0;

}
cout << *arr1 << endl;

delete [] arr1;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `arr1[i] = 0;` ... you're setting every value in the array to zero

Comment: Whenever you think "dynamic array" your next thought should almost *always* be [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: As for your problem, maybe some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) would help you understand what's going on?

Comment: try `arr1[i] = i` instead.

Comment: Oh and `*arr1` is equal to `arr1[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

There are few bugs in your code.

You expect the output to be **[0][1][2][3][4][5]** when the n = 5. Therefore your output has (n + 1) elements. So your array should also have (n + 1) elements.

```
int *arr1 = new int[n + 1];
```

In your code you assign 0 to each element in your array. But you expect the array to contain 0, 1, 2, .., n

```
for(int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++){
  arr1[i] = i;
}
```

In your code, you only print the first element. *arr1 is same as arr1[0]. So another for loop is required to print the each element in your array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++){
  cout << "[" << arr1[i] << "]" << endl;
}
```

Then you will get the output **[0][1][2][3][4][5]** when the n = 5

Comment: What are the changes you made? Why would they fix the problem the OP have? Please don't encourage cargo-cult programming.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've improved the answer such that it better reflects problems in the original code.